# Como hacer que Python ignore los valores nulos, vacíos al registrarlos con SQL

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyqt5

Como podria hacer para que el excutemany() ignore los registros con valor nulo. Que solo registre los campos que no son nulos.

```
 mycursor = mydb.cursor()
 sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, fav) VALUES(%s, %s)"
 val =[
    ('Samantha', 154),
    ('Thalia', 155),
    ('Jacobs', null),
    ('Jamie', null)]

 mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
 mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que filtrarlos tu antes, [`executemany`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.executemany) solamente sirve para ejecutar `INSERTS`  y `REPLACES` con una sola query, para optimizar rendimiento y no generar overhead.

Lo que si puede hacer es filtrarlo de forma dinámica antes de enviarlo, por ejemplo:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, fav) VALUES(%s, %s)"
val =[
    ('Samantha', 154),
    ('Thalia', 155),
    ('Jacobs', None),
    ('Jamie', None)]

val_filtered = [i for i in val if i[1] ]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
```

> PD: en python el null -> None

Comment: Ok @gilito , entiendo que tendría que filtrarlos antes, pero no entiendo a que te refieres poniendo 1 entre corchetes en .... i [1]..

Comment: Si te fijas val es una lista, cada item de esa lista es una tupla de 2 valores. i[1] accede al segundo valor de cada tupla. Ahora mejor?

Comment: efectivamente. FUNCIONA. GRACIAS